# What is the equivalent of Class.create() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I was recently converting some PrototypeJS code into jQuery, and came across `Class.create()`, and wasn't sure of the jQuery equivalent.

Any help?

Comment: Had this in my bookmarks, take a look [LINK](http://jsperf.com/jquery-class-create-vs-pure-js-function/3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery does not ship with this functionality built-in.

If you want to use something with similar syntax to the way PrototypeJS handles it, consider including in your project the [tiny **Simple JavaScript Inheritance** script](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) by John Resig (who is the original author of jQuery).

Once you include that script, you can just copy & paste your code as is. It's mostly the same. The only difference is that instead of using `Class.create`, you should use `Class.extend`.

Answer (score 0):

there is no class.create() in jquery, instead use regular JS to code the object up.

create a class with associated object and then use $.extend() to work with the object.

follow the link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/